# LibreOffice Base - query - merge two rows

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I'm learning LibreOffice Base (3.6.2). Unfortunatly the doc is pretty poor. The DB is a ".odb" file format. Here's a simple multi-table query:

[image: LibreOffice Base query]

I'd like to merge the field "refLogiciel.name" and "tblPosteLogiciel.version" in one field.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to Create the query in SQL for that one. I have the same problem. No answers yet, but I do at least have some headway in that area. Here's a link to my question, which might help:

[Error in Querying Concatenation of 2 fields in LibreOffice Base SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675770/error-in-querying-concatenation-of-2-fields-in-libreoffice-base-sql)

EDIT: Oops, I din't realize how old this post was. Hope you found out how to do it so you can share it to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

use as field: CONCAT( "refLogiciel"."name" ,  "tblPosteLogiciel"."version")
If you want a space between the two then use:
CONCAT( "refLogiciel"."name" , CONCAT( ' ',  "tblPosteLogiciel"."version"))