# Error in Querying Concatenation of 2 fields in LibreOffice Base SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, hsqldb, libreoffice-base

My apologies for wrong terminilogies, I am not actually a programmer, just a Base user confronted with a problem.

I'm having trouble querying a column which is supposed to be a concatenation of two fields of two separate tables. I'm using LibreOffice Base Version 1:3.6.2 and it has the default HSQL engine.

My two tables are as follows:

Table 1 is named `"Prefectures"` and has the following fields: ID, `"Prefecture Name"`, and `"State"`
Table 2 is named `"Ward"` and has the following fields: ID, `"Ward Name"`, and Prefecture ID which is a foreign key referencing table 1.

What I want my query to produce is these two colums: "Ward Name, Prefecture Name" as a concatenation of the Ward.WardName and Prefecture.PrefectureName, and the Ward ID

For example. If I had a prefecture named "Cebu" and a ward named "Lahug" which has a ward ID of 0, I want the query to come up with "Lahug, Cebu" on column 1, and "0" in column 2

The Base tutorial I used seems to have a modified language compared to the actual HSQL language, at least based on my programmer friends reaction. I know that attributes are referred to as `Table.Attribute`, for example, but in Base, they use `"Attribute"`, or, if I am not mistaken, when one needs to specify the table of origin, `"Table"("Attribute")`. However, I know that this modified language works because I used it to create the my two tables.

Anyways, hazarding on what I learned from Base the tutorial document, I came up with:

```
SELECT "Ward Name" || ', ' || "Prefecture Name" AS "Wrd_Pref",
       "Ward ID"
FROM "Prefecture" INNER JOIN "Ward" ON "Prefecture" ("Prefecture ID") = "Ward" ("Prefecture ID")
;
```

And the error message that came up was:
"The data content could not be loaded. Access is denied: PREFECTURE in statement [the whole code above]"

I have a suspicion this is a misread due to wrong syntax on my part. Perhaps my guess on using perentheses in this case is wrong? If so, why is the error message "Access denied"? I checked both the records and the sql codes of the two tables, both were perfectly normal.

EDIT: No, I don't want to just split the two fields. I need them concatenated as I am going to use them as list items in a dropdown list for a form I am making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query is this one. You say your tables are called "Prefectures" and "Ward", which are used in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT "Ward Name" || ', ' || "Prefecture Name" AS "Wrd_Pref", "Ward ID"
FROM "Prefectures" INNER JOIN "Ward" ON "Prefectures"."Prefecture ID" = "Ward"."Prefecture ID";
```